# how can I put a process in background using django?

Tags: python, django, process, system

I tried os.system, os.spwanl, etc.. but it doesn't work well

I need to execute some background process from django application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to put the process in background for localhost/remote hots..,

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,user,pwd,port,.......)

si, so, se = ssh.exec_command('nohup' + cmd + '&')
so.read()
se.read()
```

has resolved the issue....

Answer (score 15):

Try to use [celery](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/introduction.html). It was originally created for this purpose and also supports scheduling tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module gives you much finer-grained control over spawning processes than afforded by os.system.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to spawn background processes from Django before. It may depend on your environment, but I had no issue using it with both modpython and modwsgi.